# Calling a C DLL Function With char* Parameters With P/Invoke

Tags: c#, dll, pinvoke

I've read other similar questions on this but they don't solve this particular problem. I have an old C-library with a touppercase function (as an example). This takes a char* and returns a char*. However, the pointer returned is a pointer to the same string (don't ask me I didn't write it).

The function looks like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
char * __cdecl touppercase(char *ps_source)
{
    char *ps_buffer = NULL;

    assert (ps_source != NULL);

    ps_buffer = ps_source;
    while (*ps_buffer != '\0')
    {
        *ps_buffer = toupper(*ps_buffer);
        ps_buffer++;
    }
*ps_buffer = '\0';
    return (ps_source);
}
```

The C# code to declare this looks like:

```
    [DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint = "touppercase",
               CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true,
               CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern System.IntPtr touppercase(string postData);
```

The call to this in my app looks like

```
     string sTest2 = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(to_uppercase(sTest));
```

However sTest2 just ends up being a random string.

I added a test function to the same dll with the same parameters but this allocates memory locally and copies the string. This works fine. Why does the original version now work?

Note: Updating the dll libraries themselves isn't an option.

Comment: What happens to sTest after a call to this function? does it change?

Comment: Why are you declaring the calling convention.  By default C# uses Calling convention instead of the Standard convention ( C/C++ ).  You already change the convention in your C library.  You would only have to change the convention if the C code wasn't declared as something other then the default.

Comment: @ramhound: explicitly specifying the calling convention of exported functions is safest.  You don't want exports to be affected by `/Gr` or `/Gz`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function is modifying the reference so you should use a stringbuilder:

```
[DllImport("dll.dll", EntryPoint="touppercase",
CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true,
CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern System.IntPtr touppercase(StringBuilder postData);
```

Call it something like this:

```
    StringBuilder sTest = new StringBuilder("abs");
    touppercase(sTest);
    string result = sTest.ToString();
```

For the explanation of the return pointer -> Ben Voigt

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly observed, the return type is a pointer to the same string.  And the string provided to the function is a temporary buffer used by .NET for Unicode->ANSI conversion, deallocated before P/Invoke returns.  So it's a wild pointer which you must ignore (best to just use C# void return type).

I would also recommend using `StringBuilder` for the parameter instead of `String`, this lets .NET know that the function will change the parameter passed.  The content of the `StringBuilder` will be modified by the function, that's how you get your results without a return value.